# python excel processing error

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

I am working on the excel processing using python.
I am using xlrd module (version 0.6.1) for the same.

I am abe to fetch most of the excel files but for some excel files it gives me error as :

```
XLRDError: Expected BOF record; found 0x213c
```

Can anyone let me know about how to solve this issue?
thanks in advance.

Comment: Googling this exact error suggests these '.xls' files are not in Excel 2003 'binary' format but are xml-based (newer excel file format). You van verify by opening one in notepad. Are you sure you're using the latest XLRD version?

Comment: I am not using latest xlrd modules as our project is working with version 0.6.1

Answer (score 5):

What you have is most probably an "XML Spreadsheet 2003 (*.xml)" file ... `"<!"` aka `"\x3c\x21"` (which is what XML streams start with) is being interpreted as the little-endian number `0x213c`.

Notepad: First two lines:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
```

You can also check this by opening the file with Excel and then click on `Save As` and look at the file-type that is displayed. While you are there, save it as an XLS file so that your `xlrd` can read it.

Note: this XML file is NOT the Excel 2007+ XLSX file. An XLSX is actually a ZIP file (starts with `"PK"`, not `"<?"`) containing a bunch of XML streams.